# WinRar is acting weirdly

Tags: hard-drive, compression, zip, disk-space, winrar

I tried to unarchive a 40 gig zip archive in my d drive which at the time had 120 gigs free but i was greated by a message that i don't have enough disk space i was really confused and i decided to check out how much space i had and what i saw was that i had 0 gb of free space in my c drive and 120 in my d drive i used to have 20 gigs i pressed the cancel button that was in the error message and then i quickly got my 20 gigs back so i decided to free up some files and i had 45 gigs of free storage in my c drive and then i tried to unarchive it again and then i missclicked cancel instead of pause and now it didn't free up the space that it held i have 7 gigs free can anyone help me? maybe it created a secret folder?

Comment: You've typed 160 words without any punctuation. If you want someone to help you, at least try to make it easy for them to read your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check where WinRar keeps the temporary files it uses when compressing and decompressing. Usually it is `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp`. You can see or change its location in WinRar Options, Settings, Paths. First go to that folder and delete all the files you don't need. Then change it to a folder on a drive with plenty of space, and click OK. May need to reboot.

I did this when my SSD got nearly full.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the help that you gave me

Comment: forgot to ask where are those setting located

Comment: Sorry, it's Options, then Settings. Start WinRar using Windows Type Here To Search (next to start button), type WinRar. See image added above.